# Progress Bar with Sencha (JS)

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I am new with Sencha, Javascript and HTML. I'm trying to make a progress bar (animated) using Sencha. I don't quite get how Sencha works. I need a step by step tutorial on how to do it? I want the output to be:

1. one without status percentage, and
2. one with percentage)?

Comment: Please show us some code that you have tried ?

Comment: Hi gvmani, below are my coding:

Comment: @gvmani here is my code:

Comment: does this help http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/simple-widgets/progress-bar.html

Comment: @gvmani I'd try but still couldn't get. there's an error reading the code. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

below are my coding:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
   var pb = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
      margin: 50,ui:'default'
   });
   // Wait for 5 seconds, then update the status el (progress bar will auto-reset)
   pb.wait({
      interval: 500, //bar will move fast!
      duration: 50000,
      increment: 15,
      text: "Hi, I've got a custom UI...",
      scope: this,
      fn: function(){
         p.updateText('Done!');
      }
   });
   var pa = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
      title: "I'm a regular 'default' UI Panel",
      width: 500,
      items: pb, // put the progressbar in our panel
      floating: true,
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      closable: true
   })
})
```